# How to use a function in a compile-time constant

Tags: c, string

I am trying to declare a random string as a variable that changes each run that everything can access however my knowledge of C is very limited.

I've tried researching multiple websites and using tutorials but I cannot seem to explain it correctly.

```c
// Declare example
#define DEST_SIZE 40

char *randstring(int length) {    
    char *string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
    size_t stringLen = 26*2+10+7;        
    char *randomString;

    randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));

    if (!randomString) {
        return (char*)0;
    }

    unsigned int key = 0;

    for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {            
        key = rand() % stringLen;          
        randomString[n] = string[key];
    }

    randomString[length] = '\0';

    return randomString;
}
// char *randomHome = randstring(10);

// char * payloadPath = "~/Desktop/resign_temp_app/";

char dest[DEST_SIZE] = "~/Desktop/AppSign/";

char *randomHome = randstring(10);

char* plx = strcat(dest, randomHome);
char* plx2 = strcat(dest, "/");

const char * payloadPath = dest;


// Function Example
int rmTempAppPath(){
   char dest2[DEST_SIZE] = "rm -rf ";
   char *command = strcat(dest2, dest);
   int status = system(command);
   if (status != 0)
   {
       return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I was hoping that it would just work however I get the following error and warning messages

```
resignCore.c:39:20: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
char *randomHome = randstring(10);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
resignCore.c:41:13: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
char* plx = strcat(dest, randomHome);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:131:3: note: 
      expanded from macro 'strcat'
                __builtin___strcat_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
resignCore.c:42:14: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
char* plx2 = strcat(dest, "/");
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:131:3: note: 
      expanded from macro 'strcat'
                __builtin___strcat_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
```

I am really sorry for providing quite a bit of code and errors but I am not very good at explaining.

Comment: Can you try minimize the problem first. There is a bit too much going on. Try to get rid of those warnings first. Such as the unused variables, comment them out for now. 
Define payloadpath with const, i.e. `const char *payloadPath = dest;` and that should get rid of that warning. Make plx2 char* unless you actually want a char in which case assign a char not a char*. Once you have updated your code I will look at it again.

Comment: You can get rid of most of these warnings and errors if you search the error and warning messages online.

Comment: @Tagger5926 updated the question

Comment: Except for a very few intrinsic functions (like `sizeof()`), functions are not executed at compile time, so what you're asking will not work. Functions are run when the code is executed, not when it's compiled.

Comment: @KenWhite how can I have a random path generated that all functions can access then?

Comment: `strcat(dest, "/");` should suffice. What are you using plx2 for? It would be better if you can give a working example rather than snippets so we can see how you want to use it.

Comment: @Tagger5926, I could give a working example however I would have to upload 3 code files and I don't think StackOverflow allows that. and using just strcat(dest, "/"); made an error and that's why i made it a char.

Comment: Can't you just do `char *randomHome = NULL;` and then `randomHome = randomString();` in main(). Alright, gimme a min and I will provide an example.

Comment: I don't even have a main(), jepus.

Comment: @Tagger5926 https://imgur.com/a/F5QO9IT resign.c contains main() and resignCore.c is the code I'm trying to get working and doesn't have a main().

Comment: *I don't even have a main()` Then how are you planning on using this code? Stop. Write a simple, single file example of what you're trying to do, in the form of a [mcve] that someone here can copy from your question, paste into a code editor, compile, and run to reproduce the problem you're having. This *my code is too big, but I don't even have a main()* isn't productive for you, us, or future users of this site.

Comment: @KenWhite I do have a main, however it's in another file. The code I am trying to fix is where all the functions are declared.  Here are all three files.

Comment: resign.c - https://pastebin.com/tCchJn4Z
resignCore.c - https://pastebin.com/zVLkN1MV
resignCore.h - https://pastebin.com/THGksLfZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your code to work as a simple example.
Just for the future, it doesn't matter if your code is big. Reduce the scope of the problem. I don't need your whole project source code, just give us a simple snippet that isolates the problem as much as possible.

Now the problem was that you had global variables that you try to define with non compile-time constants. So you initialize them with compile-time constants such as `NULL` and then define then in your main function before you call your other functions.

`strcat(dest, src)` appends `src` to `dest` and the return value is `dest` as well. `char *val = strcat(dest, src)` is superfluous and error prone. So just use `strcat(dest,src)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DEST_SIZE 40

// Globals
char dest[DEST_SIZE] = "~/Desktop/AppSign/";
char *randomHome = NULL;

char *randstring(int length) {    
    const char * string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";
    size_t stringLen = sizeof(string)/sizeof(char);        
    char *randomString = NULL;
    randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));
    if (!randomString) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int n = 0;n < length;n++) {            
        unsigned int key = rand() % stringLen;          
        randomString[n] = string[key];
    }

    randomString[length] = '\0';

    return randomString;
}

void printGlobal()
{
    printf("%s",dest);
}

int main()
{
    randomHome = randstring(10);
    strcat(dest, randomHome);
    printGlobal();
    strcat(dest, "/");
    printGlobal(); // print updated dest value
}
```

Disclaimer, there will be a memory leak if you don't `delete` randomString that you generate after usage.

What I like to do sometimes, especially when I am testing new code or libraries out it create a mini project for instance a single file project. Then try to create a minimal working example. As you can see, I didn't need the other 2 files to try and debug this problem.

Comment: So, with this, since main is in a separate file to the other code will the other code still be able to use the new randomHome and dest variables?

Comment: randomHome and dest are still global. But you need to make sure they are defined because you call your other functions. I will add comments to make it clearer

Comment: If you compile this example, you should see that printGlobal() will print whatever dest is at that point of time.

Comment: Thank you that works and my script compiled and installed however it gets to where it extracts the IPA to the AppSign folder, extracts then `Abort Trap: 6` I have provided an image to show what I mean. https://imgur.com/a/GCDQRSH

Comment: and the generated string is always the same, it needs to be random each run, however that is probably something I did wrong.

Comment: You don't have a random seed. Before you run rand(). You should have something like `srand(time(NULL));`. The resolution of the seed is in seconds i believe. So if you generate random strings too quickly, your strings will turn out to be the same until a certain amount of time has passed. Check this for more info: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29198/random-string-generator-in-c

You can put `srand(time(NULL)); ` in main() but everytime main() is called, you will get the same random strings.

Comment: How do I add a random seed?

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the random issue however I still do not know what is causing the Abort Trap: 6, i will go through and have a look and if you don't mind I'll respond here with what I think may be causing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198343/discussion-between-tagger5926-and-joseph-shenton).